# Is there a way to filter two columns which either of the value in column is greater than 20?

Tags: excel, csv

I have a TSV/excel flle with numeric data. I want to filter out all the row from which either column "A" or "B" should have values greater than 15.

I tried to get the sum of the column in an additional column and filter, but it doesn't make sense if cells contains 7 and 8. also average of the column also not working if the cells has 20 and 5.

Data I have:

[image: input]

Result I need

[image: Result i need]

I'm very newbie to excel,Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a helper column, containing following formula: `=OR(A2>=20,B2>=20)`. (Start at cell C2 and drag further down)
Filtering on this helper column (value `TRUE`) will result in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use the new `FILTER`function:

`=FILTER(A2:B8;(A2:A8>15)+(B2:B8>15))`

It will spill down all rows that fulfill the criteria.

The +-sign reads as OR for the conditions.